# Javascript now playing feature

Tags: javascript, audio

i have a looping audio tag on my website playing music. if its possible to make i would like some text that says:

"Now playing: (1st song name)"

and then it switching after x amount of seconds

"Now playing: (2nd song name)"

3 minutes >

"Now playing: (3rd song name)"

3 minutes >

"Now playing: (4th song name)"

Comment: Sounds like a cool idea. What exactly have you tried by yourself to make this happen and where did you get stuck? Stack Overflow isn't really the place for getting started as much as getting finished.

Comment: i have not tried anything since im fairly new to website programming .

Comment: could you paste you code snippet

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = document.getElementById("myAudio").currentSrc;
```

this will return current Playing audio source.